# Errors occur during compilation of GWT project (GWT2.6.0) using GXT 3.1.0

Tags: gwt, sencha-touch, gxt

I am using GWT 2.6.0 and create a project,it compiled and ran without any problem but when i added the gxt.jar(version 3.1.0) in to build path and compiled it again it gave the following error.

```
Loading inherited module 'com.drishti.ameyo.ic.Com_drishti_ameyo_ic'
   Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'
      Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.data.Data'
         Loading inherited module 'com.sencha.gxt.core.Core'
            [ERROR] Line 49: Unexpected exception while processing element 'property-provider'
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.translateException(JsVisitor.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:470)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:550)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsInvocation.traverse(JsInvocation.java:69)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:468)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:445)
```

Here is the instruction link that i followed  http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/getting_started/Getting_Started_Eclipse_Standard.html#Build_path

and below is my gwt.xml file after inheriting `com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<module rename-to='com_drishti_ameyo_ic'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>



  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
  <inherits name='com.drishti.ameyo.media.dim.app.agentAvailabiltyStatusApp'/>
  <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>

  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

    <!-- GXT Stylesheet -->
        <stylesheet src="reset.css" />

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.            -->
  <entry-point class='com.drishti.ameyo.ic.client.InteractionCampaign'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path=''/>

  <set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" /> 

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points regarding your module descriptor:

- remove the following entry:
  `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>`

As long as you are using only GXT widgets, you don't need them.

- add a GXT theme:
  f.e.: `<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme'/>`
  make sure, you add the neptune theme jar to your classpath
- use client shares and server packages in your code.
  using `<source path=''/>` let GWT search your whole project.

And to your problem (as written above):
I can confirm: GWT 2.6.0 and GXT 3.1 will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually the mistake was that i was using GWT2.6.0 and gwt-servlet.jar of version 2.5.1 and in the order and import gwt-servlet.jar was above the gwt.so i replaced gwt-servlet2.5.1 to get-servlet2.6.0 and now it is working fine.